# How to pass array of values without array variable?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have put in place very nice system to add Columns into VirtualStringTree, as the old system was just too bulky.

**Old system:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    VST.Header.Columns.Clear;
    VST.Header.Columns.Add.Text:='#';
    VST.Header.Columns.Add.Text:='First name';
    VST.Header.Columns.Add.Text:='Last name';
    VST.Header.Columns.Add.Text:='Address';

    VST.Header.Columns[0].Width:=50;
    VST.Header.Columns[1].Width:=200;
    VST.Header.Columns[2].Width:=200;
    VST.Header.Columns[3].Width:=500;
end;
```

**New system with 3 additional procedures**, but much less code in executing them:

SetNames - sets column names in global array of string

SetWidths - sets column widhs in global array of integer

SetColumns - creates Columns based on global arrays values

```
var 
    gWidths:array of integer;
    gNames:array of string;

    procedure SetNames(vCount:integer; vA:string='';vB:string='';vC:string='';vD:string='';vE:string='';vF:string='';vG:string='';vH:string='';vI:string='';vJ:string='');
    begin
      SetLength(gNames,0);
      SetLength(gNames,vCount);
      If vCount>0 then gNames[0]:=vA;
      If vCount>1 then gNames[1]:=vB;
      If vCount>2 then gNames[2]:=vC;
      If vCount>3 then gNames[3]:=vD;
      If vCount>4 then gNames[4]:=vE;
      If vCount>5 then gNames[5]:=vF;
      If vCount>6 then gNames[6]:=vG;
      If vCount>7 then gNames[7]:=vH;
      If vCount>8 then gNames[8]:=vI;
      If vCount>9 then gNames[9]:=vJ;
    end;

    procedure SetWidths(vCount:integer; v1:integer=0;v2:integer=0;v3:integer=0;v4:integer=0;v5:integer=0;v6:integer=0;v7:integer=0;v8:integer=0;v9:integer=0;v10:integer=0);
    begin
      SetLength(gWidths,0);
      SetLength(gWidths,vCount);
      If vCount>0 then gWidths[0]:=v1;
      If vCount>1 then gWidths[1]:=v2;
      If vCount>2 then gWidths[2]:=v3;
      If vCount>3 then gWidths[3]:=v4;
      If vCount>4 then gWidths[4]:=v5;
      If vCount>5 then gWidths[5]:=v6;
      If vCount>6 then gWidths[6]:=v7;
      If vCount>7 then gWidths[7]:=v8;
      If vCount>8 then gWidths[8]:=v9;
      If vCount>9 then gWidths[9]:=v10;
    end;

    procedure SetColumns(vColumns:TVirtualTreeColumns; vNames:array of string; vWidths:array of integer);
    var i:integer;
    begin
      vColumns.Clear;
      for i := 0 to High(vNames) do
        vColumns.Add.Text:=vNames[i];

      for i := 0 to High(vWidths) do
        vColumns[i].Width:=vWidths[i];
    end;
```

With these global arrays and 3 new procedure I just do this, very easy, clean:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        VST.Header.Columns.Clear;

        SetNames(4,'#','First name','Last name','Address');
        SetWidths(4,50,20,20,50);
        SetColumns(VST.Header.Columns,gNames,gWidths);
    end;
```

.

**Question: Is it possible to reduce the code, skip the global arrays and extra procedure to something like:**

```
SetColumns(VST.Header.Columns,('#','First name','Last name','Address'),(50,20,20,50));
```

Comment: Hey there, take a look at is: [array as parameter and return type](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/array_parameter.htm) Is it this you are searching for?

Comment: @rocksteady not sure how you see this would help my case. Maybe to change SetNames and SetWidth to functions and use them in one call: `SetColumns(VST.Header.Columns,fSetNames(4,'#','First name','Last name','Address'), fSetWidths(4,50,20,20,50)))`?

Comment: It shows a way of passing an array as parameter to a function/procedure by declaring the array as a type: Referring to the example given in the link above: `type
   TDayVisitors = array[0..6] of integer;
 
 ...
 
 procedure DisplayWeekTotal(weekVisitors : TDayVisitors) ;` 
 I thought it might help.

Comment: Thank you, I'm evaluating answer below from LU RD, ti seems cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `SetColumns` to take const open arrays:

```
procedure SetColumns(  vColumns       : TVirtualTreeColumns;
                       const vNames   : array of string;
                       const vWidths  : array of integer);
var i:integer;
begin
  if Length(vNames) <> Length(vWidths) then
    raise Exception.Create('vNames and vWidth should have same number of elements!')
  else
  begin
    vColumns.Clear;
    for i := 0 to High(vNames) do
      with vColumns.Add do
      begin
        Text := vNames[i];
        Width := vWidths[i];
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Add brackets around the arrays [Using Open Array Constructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions#Open_Array_Constructors):

```
SetColumns(VST.Header.Columns,['#','First name','Last name','Address'],[50,20,20,50]);
```

Another alternative (uses the heap to allocate the arrays):

```
SetColumns( VST.Header.Columns,
            TArray<String>.Create('#','First name','Last name','Address'),
            TArray<Integer>.Create(50,20,20,50));
```

---

**Christmas bonus update**

In a comment the OP asks how to pass an array of a record in brackets in a similar way.

Step 1:

Declare a static class function as a member of your record returning a record:

```
Type
  TMyRecord =
    record
      myName: string;
      myValue: integer;
      class function Init(const aName: String; aValue: Integer): TMyRecord; static;
    end;

class function TMyRecord.Init(const aName: String; aValue: Integer): TMyRecord;
begin
  Result.myName := aName;
  Result.myValue := aValue;
end;
```

Step 2:

Call your `SetValues2` procedure utilizing the static initialization function:

```
procedure SetValues2(const vArr: array of TMyRecord);
begin
  ;
end;

SetValues2([TMyRecord.Init(' a ',1),TMyRecord.Init(' b ',2),TMyRecord.Init(' c ',3)]);
```

Comment: Drat! Silly phone call cost me again. :-) Nice.

Comment: I didn't know you can pass values like this, as arrays, in brackets. It seems to be working, is it new in XE7?

Comment: Yes it is a new feature in XE7. Read http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_september_dynamic_arrays_delphixe7.html.

Comment: @LU RD Maybe I'm wrong but the code above has nothing to do with the new linked feature in XE7: it's how the `Format` function is usually called. Anyway it works like the answer in XE4 too.

Comment: @fantaghirocco, yes you are correct. Updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: @fantaghirocco, but it not anything like the `Format` function, which expects an array of const. This is something else. Read [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).

Comment: @LU RD obviously the parameters meaning differs but what I meant was the construction of the array `[...]` during the call. It applies here since an `array of const` parameter is implemented like an open array of `TVarRec` behind the scene, like the doc you've linked states

Comment: This form of parameter specification, using `[...]` is known as an *open array constructor*. A link to the docs would be useful here. @Mike The language documentation is generally good. I recommend it to you.

Comment: The open array constructor is generally preferable because it avoids the overhead of heap memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks, struggling to find the correct words. And yes, the open array constructor is more efficient.

Comment: Open array constructor, good! So, I guess compiler recognizes I'm not just passing simple Set of integer, with limit of 255 max value.

Comment: It's no risk the compiler confuses this with a set type in this case.

Comment: It might be out of scope of this question, but I'm testing this in my code and I'm trying to make it work for `TMyRecord = record myName:string; myValue:integer; end; ... var  array of TMyRecord;` how would I pass parameters in brackets for this type of array? This doesn't work: `procedure SetValues2(vArr:array of TMyRecord);     SetValues2([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]);`

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping it's again just a trick with brackets.